# Реализовать случайный выбор заранее заданных чисел

Tags: c#

Есть числа 500, 800, 900, 100, 200. Можно ли сделать рандом из конкретно этих чисел без использования массива?

```
Random rand = new Random();
var array = new[] {500, 800, 900, 100, 200};
var rndMember = array[rand.Next(array.Length)];
Console.WriteLine(rndMember);
```

Тоже самое реализовать, но без использования массива

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `Можно ли сделать рандом из конкретно этих чисел без использования массива?` А как вы узнаете из каких чисел выбирать?

Comment: если под "конкретно этими" числами вы подразумеваете числа из вопроса, то элементарно: `var x = Random.Shared.Next(1, 5) * 100`

Comment: Если вопрос решен, вы можете выбрать наиболее полезный ответ и отметить его принятым, для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 6):

Можно

```
Random rnd = Random.Shared;
int result = rnd.Next(5) switch
{
    0 => 100,
    1 => 200,
    2 => 500,
    3 => 800,
    _ => 900
};
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
class RandomOfNumbers {
    static void Main() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            var r = rand.Next(1, 6) * 100;
            r = r < 300 ? r : r < 400 ? 500 : r + 400;
            Console.Write("{0} ", r);
        }
    }
}

800 800 800 200 200 100 200 200 800 200 100 100 900 500 800 200 900 800 900 200 900
500 800 100 800 500 500 500 200 500 200 800 900 100 200 500 200 100 100 500 800 100
200 500 900 800 200 800 500 800 100 500 900 500 500 200 900 800 500 800 800 800 900
200 100 500 200 900 100 200 900 900 800 200 500 800 100 200 200 100 100 800 100 800
200 900 800 500 500 100 500 500 800 200 800 100 200 100 500 200
```